# Adding second php sql query to order results from two different tables

Tags: php, sql

I've searched over the internet but since i'm beginner with php i ve countered some problems. I have a script that orders some gameserver characters by level and points. Ordering by level was easy.

The database is : `cDtb`
Table name which contains `Level` field is `Character`.

Now, i would like to use a second query in the same script that will order after `Points` field and the table name is called `Reward`. I have tried to add as second query like the first one but it's not showing any result.

The end result should sort by decreasing values and using the results from the two tables `Character` and `Reward`, starting with Points and then Level

Saying ... usernames Test1 and Tes2 got same level 100 but Test1 got 30Points and Test2 35Points which in this case, the rank will be Test2, Test1

Can someone help me on how to add the second query and how it should look like to order both by points and level?

Thanks in advance, below is the script

```
    <tr>
    <td><div align="center">Level</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">Points</div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>                    

    <?
    $query=mssql_query("select TOP 15 * from cDtb.dbo.Character order by Level desc");
//---------- second query ??? --------------
    while($row=mssql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $levelz=$row['Level'];
    $pointz=$row['Points'];


    ?>


    <td style="color: rgb(196, 37, 0); font-weight: bold;">
    <div align="center">
    <td><?=$levelz;?></td>
    <td><?=$pointz;?></td> 
    </div></td>

    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by a second field in the same result set like this:

```
select TOP 15 * from cDtb.dbo.Character order by Level desc, Points desc;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It won't work since Points is inside another table called Reward and NOT inside Character. So it should be select TOP 15 * from cDtb.dbo.Reward order by Points desc; but if i add this second query, only the rank ordered by Points will be shown and not the Level too

Comment: Are you able to join these two tables together using a foreign key? If you can, then you'll be able to use the double ORDER BY..

Comment: No i wont be able to do this thats why i need to include the second query or so inside this script